# Why did Google sign every auxiliary app inside "Google Chrome.app" (OS X version) except for one?

Tags: google, macos, chrome, code-signing

```
$ codesign -dvv /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Versions\
/46.0.2490.80/Google\ Chrome\ Framework.framework/Resources/app_mode_loader.app/

/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions\
/46.0.2490.80/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Resources/app_mode_loader.app/\
: code object is not signed at all
```

You may need to adjust the version number after "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions" to match yours.

Answer (score 2):

> We can't sign the app_mode_loader bundle because it's altered at runtime
>   as new app mode loader stubs are created. We can sign just the
>   executable. The resulting executable won't validate in its bundle
>   normally, and spctl won't like it, but it can be verified with
>   --ignore-resources, or in isolation from its bundle.

https://codereview.chromium.org/1486863003